# How can I Save and Load Javascript Byte Array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to store MIDI sysex data in MongoDB. When I try to load the data I get a javascript object. I can see the byte values when I JSON.stringify the object but I can't figure out how to access the bytes.

The data in MongoDB looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
    console.log(`getSysexProgram 1 ${JSON.stringify(preset.program.sysex)}`)
    let byteArray: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(preset.program.sysex);
    console.log(`getSysexProgram 2 ${JSON.stringify(byteArray)}`)
```

Output:

```
getSysexProgram 1 {"0":0,"1":80,"2":82,"3":79,"4":71,"5":82,"6":101, ...
getSysexProgram 2 {}
```

Comment: Instead of image, please post the code snippet.

Comment: Maybe you want to store `"sysex"` as an array, rather than an object?

Comment: You could convert `preset.program.sysex` to an array with `Object.entries(preset.program.sysex).map(([idx, val]) => val)`, but storing it as an array in the first place seems more like what you want.

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs I that worked. I just set the return values to the byte array. Now I can see in MongoDB that the object has changed to an array and all is well.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I can't copy the text out of the Realms UI